# Business logic works but Mongoose save doesn't

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I'm trying to save data from my shopping cart app to MongoDB database. In my cart controller folder, there are `getAllProducts`, `addOneProduct`, `removeOneProduct` and `updateOneProducts` methods. All of them run perfectly fine except for `updateOneProducts`.

The console.log shows:

`GET all product { id: [1,2,4], qty: [1,1,1] }`

`UPDATE one product { id: [1,2,4], qty: [1,1,2] }`

which indicate that the business logic works. However, the document is not updated on mLab.

**User model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  userID: String,
  picture: String,
  products: {
    id: [Number],
    qty: [Number],
  }
});

const Users = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = Users;
```

**updateOneProduct**

```
const extractProduct = (user) => {
  const product = {};
  product.id = user.products.id;
  product.qty = user.products.qty;

  return product;
}

// if user is logged in n changes the qty of a product, update the qty in database
const updateOneProduct = (req, res) => {
  // if (!req.user) return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized' });
  const userId = req.user._id;
  const event = req.body.event;
  const productId = req.body.id;

  return Users.findById(userId)
              .then(user => {
                const qty = user.products.qty;
                const index = user.products.id.indexOf(productId);
                if (index === -1) {
                  throw new Error(`Product doesn't exist!`);
                }

                const regex = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
                if (event === 'plus') {
                  qty[index] += 1;
                } else if (event === 'minus') {
                  qty[index] -= 1;
                } else if (regex.test(event) && event !== '0') {
                  qty[index] = Number(event);
                }

                if (qty[index] === 0) {
                  user.products.id.splice(index, 1);
                  qty.splice(index, 1);
                }

                return user.save();
              })
              .then(user => {
                const product = extractProduct(user);
                console.log('UPDATE one product', product);
                return res.status(200).json(product);
              })
              .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error }));
}
```

Comment: you are not getting data from User instead of product

Comment: Hi the product object is in the User model as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

So I basically cloned user.products.qty array with `const qty = [...user.products.qty]`, do operations on it and replace user.products.qty with it using `user.products.qty = qty`. Lastly, I save it with `return user.save()`.

For some reason, I can't mutate subdocument project and save it. I have to replace the whole subdocument user.products then save for it to work. I think it might also have something to do with this being a PUT request.

```
// if user is logged in n changes the qty of a product, update the qty in database
const updateOneProduct = (req, res) => {
  // if (!req.user) return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized' });
  const userId = req.user._id;
  const event = req.body.event;
  const productId = req.body.id;

  return Users.findById(userId)
              .then(user => {
                const qty = [...user.products.qty];
                const index = user.products.id.indexOf(productId);
                if (index === -1) {
                  throw new Error(`Product doesn't exist!`);
                }

                const regex = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
                if (event === 'plus') {
                  qty[index] += 1;
                } else if (event === 'minus') {
                  qty[index] -= 1;
                } else if (regex.test(event) && event !== '0') {
                  qty[index] = Number(event);
                }

                if (qty[index] === 0) {
                  user.products.id.splice(index, 1);
                  qty.splice(index, 1);
                }

                user.products.qty = qty;

                return user.save();
              })
              .then(user => {
                console.log('UPDATE - After save promise', user.products);
                return res.status(200).json(user.products);
              })
              .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error }));
}
```